# What is the best way to manage access to web controller in java?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have some question. What is the best way to manage access to web controller in java? 
For example I have users and projects.

Each user can have several projects, but I don't want, that anyone has access to my project. How I can manage it? By writing some code in every controller, to check the permissions? Or are there some framework for it? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Spring Security can support this kind of operation, or you can simply make sure users are only viewing objects they own/have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html) can help you with that.

Comment: In spring security I can add role, but I need to check if project mine or not.